# Form POST to self with Cookie Ok for Mobile?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I have a choice for user for either UK or US, on a drop down box.
This then uses the 'OnChange' submit.
It then will post to self and on post will store data as cookie.

It will use this cookie to then display the correct data to the user.
It will also use this cookie to show the current selection on the drop down so user can amend it to another choose.

Is this the best way to achieve this task? and it is also friendly with mobile?

**EDIT**
I want to use the jQuery method I think this seems fluid.
I want to use Cookies as I need to run SQL statement based on the value of the cookie (so needs to be sent via header to the server)

Is the following correct?
Header.
Add jQuery & jQuery cookie Addon.

```
 <script src="path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
 <script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
```

The Body

```
<select class="selectordropdown">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<script>
$( ".selectordropdown" )
    .change(function() {
    var selectvalue = $( ".selectordropdown" ).val();    
    $.cookie("cookiename", selectvalue {expires : 10, path: "/", domain "domain.com"});
    });
</script>
```

In the body - i believe that...
when the selectordrop down changes.
It takes the value of the drop down and stores it in a cookie?

Is this the correct way of achieving this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have to post the data if you only put it into a cookie? That's easily done with JS alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Javascript as way easier!

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NnvTR/

The HTML

```
Choose Year

<select name="yearchoice" onchange="setCookie('mycookiename',this.value,30)">

<option value='2010'>2010</option>
<option value='2011'>2011</option>
<option value='2012'>2012</option>
<option value='2013'>2013</option>

</select>
```

The script

```
<script>function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}</script>
```

Then whilst testing I used this PHP to view the Cookies. (in PHP)

```
  <?php
echo '<br><br><br>';
print_r($_COOKIE);
  ?>
```

Hope this helps someone - thank for the pointers people!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use POST for that. You can do this pretty easy with JavaScript.

Need some help?

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

On change get the value of the dropdown selection and add it to a variable:

var dd = $( "select.foo option:selected").val();

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Then either use the value to do whatever updates you need to do or store it as a cookie (as other posters have highlighted) or use localStorage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

**EDIT**
Just to clarify, get rid of the form post - it's not needed here, there are easier / better ways to do what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Even better than cookies would be to use local storage and JavaScript(If Internet Explorer 7 and earlier are not a concern for you).

A simple example:

```
    var el = document.getElementById("dropdownbox");
    if(typeof) Storage) !== "undefined") {

    el.onchange = function() {
        sessionStorage.userSelected = el.value;
    }
}
```

From there you can access what the user selected from **sessionStorage.userSelected**

That will store the information for the browser session. If you need to keep the value longer than the browsing session you use localStorage instead of sessionStorage, and the syntax is exactly the same.

Also, if Storage is not available you can fall back to old fashioned cookie. But really there is no need to even use PHP for this, it can be done very easily using JavaScript. No need to POST anything.